# фраза контракта "по согласованию между сторонами"

Tags: пунктуация

Фраза из контракта: Настоящее Дополнительное соглашение является неотъемлемой частью Контракта, вступает в силу с даты его подписания Сторонами, по согласованию между Сторонами, составлено на русском и английском языках.

Правильно ли расставлены запятые? Начальница настаивает, что последняя запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

Если `по согласованию между Сторонами` относится к последней части (а не к предыдущей, что более логично) и обозначает, что по договорённости соглашение составлено на русском и английском, то последняя запятая не нужна.

Но в английском языке в таких случаях ставится запятая.

Теоретически можно убрать последнюю запятую или предпоследнюю, в зависимости от того, куда относиться `по согласованию между Сторонами`.

Похожий пример из словаря-справочника:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

В перечисление свойств соглашения (а оно *является*, *вступает*) не входит часть «по согласованию между Сторонами». Да и «Соглашение... по согласованию» — оборот тавтологичный и избыточный для этой фразы. А то, что составлен документ на двух языках, является лишь формальным обстоятельством. Оно может быть обозначено только в последующем предложении.

*Настоящее Дополнительное соглашение является неотъемлемой частью Контракта, вступает в силу с даты его подписания Сторонами.
Соглашение составлено на русском и английском языках.*